# How to center a modal Form on a specific Panel of a SplitContainer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, splitcontainer

I have GUI which is split in two pieces using a SplitContainer Control.
One part is a navigation Panel, the other a workspace Panel.

When I open the app, on start-up a new Form appears (using `ShowDialog()`), to welcomes Users. I would like to show it centered in the middle of the workspace Panel.

Is there anybody who knows how to solve this?

```
 Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     frmWelcome.ShowDialog()
 End Sub
```

Comment: Show us some code (how you open that form) to get some help.

Comment: @PavlinII i added but i don't know is it useful for you?. frmWelcome opens at the center of MainForm. Main form also has a panel named pnlWorkspace i would like to open new form (frmWelcome) at the center of pnlWorkspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that Panel2 is your `WorkSpace` Panel, use its [PointToScreen()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen) method to calculate the Screen coordinates of `frmWelcome` and position it in the middle.

Be sure to set your `frmWelcome.StartPosition = Manual`, in the Designer or in its Constructor.

Here, I'm using the `Shown` event, to be sure that the pre-set positions in `MainForm` are already set.

```
Private Sub MainForm_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Dim p As Point = New Point(
        ((SplitContainer1.Panel2.ClientSize.Width) \ 2) - frmWelcome.Width \ 2,
        ((SplitContainer1.Panel2.ClientSize.Height) \ 2) - frmWelcome.Height \ 2)

    frmWelcome.Location = SplitContainer1.Panel2.PointToScreen(p)
    frmWelcome.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: You're great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the properties on forms to do this.

set the frmWelcome form property `StartPosition` to `CenterScreen`.

If you want it center of the screen opening it, you will have to setup `MDI` but from there you can do `frmWelcome.ShowDialog(Me)` and set the property `StartPosition` to `CenterParent`.

Hope this helps!