# Show Form in Center of Panel of Parent form

Tags: c#, winforms

**Description** I have 2 Form

1. FormMain   (Main Form with Maximized screen)
2. FormCats    (small form which i want to display in center of Panel of FormMain)

**What i tried**

```
 int X = Panel2.width + ((panel3.width/2) - FormCats.width -2);
```

> and assign this X location to FormCat

**Problem**
This is gud to get X location but on different screen resolutions its not working.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what is happening then? What is the issue you're encountering

Comment: Form not loading at exact center of FormMain. Its little bit right left...

Comment: It should be off a lot more than that.  Copy/paste the *real* code you use, including the code that creates the FormCats object.  If you set its TopLevel property to false then that needs to be visible in the snippet.

Comment: Is your application maximized? WinForms does not change the Size of panels / forms when the window is maximized afaik, I used to have issues with that as well. Could be that

Comment: See this: [How to center show.dialog form on parent panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898788/how-to-center-show-dialog-form-on-parent-panel?answertab=active#tab-top). You can easily adapt it.

Comment: @Glubus I think it does changes the size of panels, when they have the `Dock` property set or when they have certain `anchor` properties set

Comment: @Glubus my app is maximized. and Dock property is set on Panel 3 (Dock:Fill)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is center FormCat over Panel3 of the FormMain, regardless as to whether the form is maximized, ignore Panel2. Adjust FormCat using the Panel3 **screen** Location coordinates plus half its size minus half of FormCat's size.

For example:

```
Point panel3ScreenLocation = panel3.PointToScreen(panel3.Location);
int X = panel3ScreenLocation.X + (panel3.Width/2) - (FormCat.Width/2);
int Y = panel3ScreenLocation.Y + (panel3.Height/2) - (FormCat.Height/2);
FormCat.Location = new Point(X, Y);
```